# How to retrieve text written on the button element in Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<button class="btn">Enable</button>
```

This is my button element. I want to retrieve "Enable" back to my program.

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[16]/td[4]/div/button")).getText.matches("Enable"))


{
    System.out.println("Test Pass");
    //return true;
}
else
{System.out.println("Test Failed");
    //return false;
}
```

Comment: use getAttribute("value");

Comment: What are you trying to this? Do you want to find text on that button element only or you hv to do something new? your test case will fail always as currently, you hv used " .matches("Enable").

Comment: Let me know whether you are looking for button's enabled property or you wanted to verify button's text?

Answer (score 4):

```
<button name="btnK" id="gbqfba" aria-label="Google Search" class="gbqfba"><span id="gbqfsa">Google Search</span></button>
```

Button tag has multiple attributes 'name', 'id', 'class' and 'aria-label' and has values for each attribute. To get the attribute value using selenium WebDriver, we can use `element.getAttribute(attributeName)`

In your case:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[16]/td[4]/div/button");

    if(button.getAttribute("name").matches("Enable"))
    {
        System.out.println("Test Pass");
        //return true;
    }
    else{
       System.out.println("Test Failed");
        //return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake. The function is `.getText()`. The brackets are missing in my code.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply get the text from the button.

```
    WebElement buttonText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[16]/td[4]/div/button"));

    if(buttonText.getText().equals("Enable")) {
        System.out.println("Test Pass");
        //return true;
    } else{
        System.out.println("Test Failed");
        //return false;
    }
```

Or

```
WebElement buttonText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[16]/td[4]/div/button"));
Assert.assertEquals("Buton Nmae", buttonText.getText());
```